# Gain control in Android

Tags: android, audio

I am confused. I read [here](http://www.audio-evolution.com/manual/doku.php?id=android_limitations) that Android has no support for gain control (this article is dated 2013/09/21). and I found `AutomaticGainControl` class in `AudioEffect`. what does "software gain control means"? any difference?
Is it used by default while using `AudioRecord` or i have to call it?

Comment: Its [automatic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377481/how-avoid-automatic-gain-control-with-audiorecord)

Comment: is there a chance that this automatic gain control is increasing distortion? is there a way to disable it?

Comment: Yes that is a possibility check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23435951/automatic-gain-controlagc-for-external-mic)